# No files matching pattern "java" in directory when Running Sonar on Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Im using Jenkins for my builds and trying to run Sonar after the job is done.
It actually already worked but now I'm always getting this error message and I don't really changed anything in my opinion.

Exception in thread "main":

```
org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: No files matching pattern "java" in directory.
```

The Directory Exists and there is definitely Java Code in there. I check out a fresh copy of the whole svn source everytime I do a build. Its actually the jenkins job folder where the checked out source code is after a job finished. Its still there till I start a new build.

I don't get why Sonar is failing to get that sourcecode.

Did anyone had problems like that ? I'm using the newest Versions of Sonar and Jenkins I just did another update this morning. Still the same problem. For Configuration I use Sonar property files which get checkout to the Jenkins job folder aswell. He finds these files and want to check the folders configured in that file but then fails.

Comment: Please provide more detail about your configuration (maybe even screenshots). This is definitely a misconfiguration on your side. Please also give more details about your environment (version of Sonar, of Sonar Jenkins Plugin, of the Sonar Runner used inside Jenkins if this is the case, ...etc)

Comment: what i dont get is how this could happen because i didn't change anything. And there is the source code in this folder it is there. I checked it like 10 times. Jenkins is Version 1.511 Sonar is 3.2.1.. Jenkins Sonar Plugin is 2.0.1 .. Sonar Runner comes with the Jenkins Sonar Plugin i think? Well in my Configuration i have: sonar.sources=src/java He says no Java Matching in  project/src .. but there is code in project/src/java/com/bla/bla/file.java theres actually not even another folder only the java folder.

Comment: Are you building your project with Maven or another build tool? If with Maven, you should use the PostBuild action instead of the "Sonar Runner" build step. And you upgraded from which version of the Sonar Jenkins plugin?

Comment: No i dont use maven thats the thing .. im using ant. I didnt even update the Sonar Jenkins Plugin. In fact it didn't work from one day to the other..